# Every other something

Tags: phrases

I'm a bit confused with the usage of "every other *something*"

I know that "every other" means each alternate in a series of things.
However, the phrase "I interviewed 6 developers using the same test. Mark got it right, every other developer got it wrong", I believe it means only Mark got it right, not that 3 out of 6 developers got it right.

How can you tell when it's one meaning or the other?

Comment: Context. Do you have any example where it's genuinely ambiguous? If it makes sense to alternate things, then it probably mean alternate; if things aren't in an order, or if you've already been told about one thing and the rest are likely to be different, then "every other" means the rest. (Lots of words have multiple meanings, and people manage OK.)

Comment: @StuartF That looks like an answer.

Comment: first developer [wrong] second developer [right] third developer [wrong] fourth developer [right] OR the opposite way, switch wrong and right. Same idea.

Comment: This can be confusing.  To avoid that, say "Mark got it right, all the other developers got it wrong."

Comment: Only common sense can distinguish them. Something AI lacks. But ambiguity cannot be ruled out.  "I sat in this chair because every other seat was taken."  That's why we're not limited to one sentence communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first refer to a specific item or items in a set, "every other X" will usually mean "every X other than the ones that were identified". This is the case in your example sentence.

But if you haven't specified anything, and the items in the set are sequential, "every other" means every 2nd item in the sequence.

The same sentence could appear in either context. For example:

> Every other house on the block is painted red.

By itself, this means every 2nd house. But if you precede it with

> The first house on the block is painted white.

it means all the houses other than the first.

If there's any possibility of ambiguity, you can use other wording. "All the rest" clearly means all items other than the identified ones. And for alternating in a sequence you can say

> The houses are painted alternating red and white down the block.

Comment: "every other" depends on whether the first is right or wrong.